# Prometheus - prometheus.yml invalid target

Tags: spring, yaml, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, prometheus-java

I've been tryint to set up prometheus on my project but I'm having an issue when setting the targeton on prometheus.yml

I've already did everything else, added dependencies and I'm using prometheus through spring actuator

My local URL is localhost.tac.com:8080 and to hit the metrics I go to localhost.tac.com:8080/actuator/prometheus.

And this is my prometheus.yml... Could anyone tell me why is it not working with for me? I've also tried the 'targets' as localhost:8080 / localhost.tac.com:8080/actuator/prometheus and same result

I know the question is not really technical but I've been trying this for a lot of time, thanks!

EDIT: I'm using prometheus inside a remote desktop I connecto to... I connecto to this desktop, I open Eclipse, start the server, log in to an authentication page and then I'm able to use localhost.tac.com... I've downloaded prometheus insdie this remote desktop and I'm trying to run it through there. Maybe there is an issue with prometheus resolving this?

```
# my global config
global:
scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
# scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).



# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
alertmanagers:
- static_configs:
- targets:
# - alertmanager:9093



# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
# - 'first_rules.yml'
# - 'second_rules.yml'



# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
# The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
- job_name: 'prometheus'



# metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
# scheme defaults to 'http'.



static_configs:
- targets: ['localhost:9090']



- job_name: 'api'
metrics_path: /actuator/prometheus
scrape_interval: 5s
static_configs:
- targets: ['localhost.tac.com:8080']
```

Comment: Can you insert your actual prometheus.yaml text, not a screenshot. Thx

Comment: I've just inserted it thanks. I've also added a small edit that should be relevant.

Comment: Does the prometheus job work (the one on `localhost:9090`) ? Also does it work if you do a `curl localhost.tac.com:8080/actuator/prometheus` from where your prometheus server run ?